# Click on label, to select one option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Exists a method for click in label and select one specific option into select?
I don't like use JS
Follow the code:

```
<label for="a">State</label>
<select name="">
    <option value="">teste</option>
    <option value="">teste X</option>
    <option value="" id="a">teste A</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get what you want. However, `id` **MUST** be **unique**. You **can't** have multiple elements with `id="a"`

Comment: Sorry, i don't see this. Fixed.

Comment: if you dont want to use javascript, why did u added javascript and jquery tags?

Comment: `"I don't like use JS"` - Then you're going to find it *very* difficult to create dynamic functionality in web pages.  JavaScript is the language to use for tasks like this, accept it.

Comment: Why use js if I can do without? In emergency will use!

Comment: @SergioAndrade But you cannot! In fact, you could mimic it surely in some way but doesn't really worth it

Comment: @A.Wolff if is not possible, patience! Thanks for try help me

Comment: @SergioAndrade Everything (nearly) is possible, but does it worth it: https://jsfiddle.net/wfdoc78a/  ???  And ya, you should use js, that's the purpose of it

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<label data-value="c">C</label>
<select name="" id="myselect">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "label", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#myselect").val($(this).data("value"));
});
```